# Vulkan default coord system for vertex positions

Tags: vulkan

I'm studing Vulkan coordinate system stuff by working on a toy renderer.
I'm confused about coordinates of vertex positions.
Online Vulkan info, such as this:
https://matthewwellings.com/blog/the-new-vulkan-coordinate-system/

...mention that +X is right, +Y is down, and +Z is back.

In my renderer, +Z is pointing forward and I can't figure out why.
I have a triangle defined like this:

```
    // CCW is facing forward
    std::vector<PosColorVertex> vertexBuffer = {
        {{ 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f}, {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f}},
        {{-1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f},  {0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f}},
        {{ 1.0f, 1.0f, -5.0f}, {0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f}},
    };
```

That -5(Z) moves the vertex back, into the screen. It should be +5 that does that.

The coordinate system seems to be like this:
[image]

If I place the camera at the origin, it looks like this:

[image]

Another shot, with the camera away from the triangle (view translated by -4 on Z).

[image]

Some relevant code. Both model & view matrix are identity.

VS:

```
 outColor = inColor;
 gl_Position = ubo.projectionMatrix * ubo.viewMatrix * ubo.modelMatrix * vec4(inPos.xyz, 1.0);
```

FS:

```
outFragColor = vec4(inColor, 1.0);
```

Projection is:

```
glm::perspective(glm::radians(60.0f), w/h, 0.1, 256.0);
```

Comment: Which GLM settings are you using? Are you sure you understand what `glm::perspective` does for you, and which choices does it make?

Comment: GLM settings: GLM_FORCE_RADIANS, GLM_FORCE_DEPTH_ZERO_TO_ONE

Comment: glm::perspective(): Creates a frustum and turns the world space coords into clip space. Anything outside of that frustum is clipped.  I'm not sure what are all the choices it makes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Clip, and normalized device coordinates

Clip coordinates are those we get from the vertex shader. Normalized device coordinates (NDC) are the same, but divided by **w**. There are two common user options (left-handed, and right-handed):

[image: NDH]

What "up" means is actually up to you. But if you want it to be compatible with virtually all presentation engines, you want "up" to mean **-y** after the viewport transform (so in NDH your "up" should be **-y** in case of vanilla viewport transform, or it should be **+y** in case viewport transform later flips it).

The choice of "up" being always **-y** in framebuffer\image coordinates is because surface coordinates on virtually all presentation engines assume upper-left origin:

[image: surface coordinates]

Many image file formats also assume the same.

### World coordinates

World coordinates are the ones that are perfectly up to you. And via the vertex shader you transform the world coordinates into the clip coordinates Vulkan can process.

You did this via your `glm::perspective`.

Let's first actually see what we have:

```
std::vector<PosColorVertex> vertexBuffer = {
    {{ 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f}, {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f}},
    {{-1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f},  {0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f}},
    {{ 1.0f, 1.0f, -5.0f}, {0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f}},
};
```

Now, this is again highly up to interpretation what this actually means. We need another "up" reference direction.

To stay sane, we would perhaps like "up" to be in the increasing direction of **y**. So that means we got some red corner at the bottom. We got one green corner at upper left. And we got one blue corner at upper right. Or so I assume was the author's intent.

Additionally to stay sane we would prefer right-handed coordinate system. So, if we have chosen that **+y** means "up" and **+x** means "right", then **-z** gotta be "front" (and **+z** gotta be "back"):

[image: World coordinates]

(This is something that matches e.g. how Blender have world coordinates.) Now we got ourselves in bit of a pickle though. Our **z** is negative instead of positive as required by NDH. And our **y** points the other way than in NDH compared to "up". Whatever transform we do, we need to make these match.

### What does `glm::perspective()` do

`glm::perspective()` primarily does make it look, well perspectivy. But for that it needs to do couple of assumptions.

The easy one is depth. In Vulkan in NDC it is zero to one. Conveniently there is `GLM_FORCE_DEPTH_ZERO_TO_ONE`. That instucts `perspective()` that it should map your `near` and `far` to `0` and `1`, respectively. (The defualt is -1 to 1, which would not work in Vulkan unless manually corrected.) The **x** and **y** are still always -1 to 1.

Second choice is handedness. Right-handed is default. Left-handed needs `GLM_FORCE_LEFT_HANDED`. Or it can be used explicitly for the single function, e.g. `perspectiveRH()`. It is slightly misleading. What this actually means here is that "right-handed" implies "front" being **-z**. And "left-handed" means the projection assumes "front" is into positive direction of **z**:

[image]

Third choice is what is "up". `glm::perspective()` does not do anything with this actually, and the polarity of **y** stays the same througout the transform. If we want **+y** to mean "up", we need to do this manually. Either we can make use of the viewport flip feature, or we can bake it into the view-projection matrix: `proj[1][1] = -proj[1][1]`.

[image]

### How to test this stuff

It is actually pretty straightforwar to test this. This code can be used for the purpose:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

#define GLM_FORCE_RADIANS
#define GLM_FORCE_DEPTH_ZERO_TO_ONE
//#define GLM_FORCE_LEFT_HANDED
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>

int main(){
#ifdef GLM_FORCE_LEFT_HANDED
    const float near = 1.0f;
    const float far = 2.0f;
#else //right-handed
    const float near = -1.0f;
    const float far = -2.0f;
#endif

    glm::vec3 right { 1.0f,  0.0f, near};
    glm::vec3 left  {-1.0f,  0.0f, near};
    glm::vec3 up    { 0.0f,  1.0f, near};
    glm::vec3 down  { 0.0f, -1.0f, near};
    glm::vec3 front { 0.0f,  0.0f, (far-near) + near };
    glm::vec3 back  { 0.0f,  0.0f, (near-far) + near };


    const auto xform = glm::perspective(glm::radians(60.0f), 1.0f, std::abs(near), std::abs(far));

    auto r = xform * glm::vec4(right , 1.0f);
    auto l = xform * glm::vec4(left  , 1.0f);
    auto u = xform * glm::vec4(up    , 1.0f);
    auto d = xform * glm::vec4(down  , 1.0f);
    auto f = xform * glm::vec4(front   , 1.0f);
    auto b = xform * glm::vec4(back  , 1.0f);


    std::cout << "Right to clip: ("  << r.x << ", " << r.y << ", " << r.z << ", " << r.w << ")\n";
    std::cout << "Left to clip: ("   << l.x << ", " << l.y << ", " << l.z << ", " << l.w << ")\n";
    std::cout << "Up to clip: ("     << u.x << ", " << u.y << ", " << u.z << ", " << u.w << ")\n";
    std::cout << "Down to clip: ("   << d.x << ", " << d.y << ", " << d.z << ", " << d.w << ")\n";
    std::cout << "Front to clip: ("  << f.x << ", " << f.y << ", " << f.z << ", " << f.w << ")\n";
    std::cout << "Back to clip: ("   << b.x << ", " << b.y << ", " << b.z << ", " << b.w << ")\n";
}
```

For both handedness settings, we get:

```
Right to clip: (1.73205, 0, 0, 1)
Left to clip: (-1.73205, 0, 0, 1)
Up to clip: (0, 1.73205, 0, 1)
Down to clip: (0, -1.73205, 0, 1)
Front to clip: (0, 0, 2, 2)
Back to clip: (0, 0, -2, 0)
```

Ups, it all gets clipped away. But anyway "right" and "up" is positive number. So yea, we might want to flip **y** some way to be compatible with presentation engine coordinates. "front" is (0,0,1) direction, and "back" stops existing.

Note what changes in the code is the direction of **z** as used in the world coordinates.

Comment: That test program gives me this: `Right to clip: (1.73205, 0, -1, 1)
Left to clip: (-1.73205, 0, -1, 1)
Up to clip: (0, 1.73205, -1, 1)
Down to clip: (0, -1.73205, -1, 1)
Front to clip: (0, 0, 2, 2)
Back to clip: (0, 0, -4, 0)`

Comment: The fundamental issue that I'm having is that it seems my coord system is defaulting to a left-handed system. Per your definition of 'back', it seems I have +Z towards back, while +Y is down.

Comment: 2 minor nitpicks: The triangle would have red at the bottom, green to the right, blue on the left, because its CCW facing. Blender has Z up, not Y.

Comment: I think I see what the problem is. I was assuming that, by default, the camera points towards the +Z axis, but it points towards -Z. So, the fix is to invert the view-matrix's Z axis.

Comment: @Dess Blender have Z up, because the camera starts with non-zero values. If you reset its rotation, then it is +Y up.

Comment: @Dess  I did not cover trubles with facingness, but should not matter at all. Your RGB = (0,1,0) vertex is at (-1, 1), therefore left (x=-1) up (y=1).

Comment: @Dess Yes that might be the problem. As I was saying "righ-handed" system (glm default) means camera points to **-z** (i.e. the `perspective()` will flip it to **+z** to be correct in NDC). Left-handed (`GLM_FORCE_LEFT_HANDED`) would assume camera points at **+z** and wont flip it in `perspective()` .